# Docusign: Creating a Document with dynamic content

Tags: docusignapi

I have a document that is very similar to a Purchase Order that needs to be sent out for a signature through DocuSign. 
There's header type data that is fixed and can easily be placed on the document and then filled with tabs.
Along with this, there are Details which may be 1 or more. I'm wondering what the best strategy to use is to create this type of Document with Docusign API?

Edit: Including a sample of the PDF that needs to be produced:
[image: Sample Document to be sent]

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really asking about dynamically creating a document first and foremost, then getting it signed via DocuSign.

You have a number of options:

**Create a pdf dynamically**. There are many libraries available for doing this. Just google for "creating a pdf ".

**Create an html document dynamically**, then either send it to DocuSign directly or first send it to a company that specializes in making nice documents from dynamic data. I like [WebMerge](https://www.webmerge.me/#) for this.

When you send the doc to DocuSign, I agree with Rickey that Anchor Strings are a good way to have the signature in the right place. There's a [recipe for placing DocuSign fields by using anchor strings](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/autoplace).

Comment: Thank you Larry. You are correct. My biggest issue is the dynamic creation of the document. The tool I'm using to work with this will generate the PDF for me but it doesn't give me access to that file in a RESTful web service call. It only let's me access files in an email. I guess I'll post a separate question on whether DocuSign allows the submission of document through email.

Comment: Thanks for the check. I suggest that you contact the service that you're using and say that you need the pdf as a file, not sent to someone. If they won't help then you can either stop using that service, or create your own email listener, and have the service email the pdf to that. Definitely a pain, but doable. To maintain state, you can email to listener+<id>@your_domain.com. The email will be delivered to listener@your_domain, but you can pull out the id from the TO address to re-create the state (job number, customer number, etc)

Comment: Thank you Larry. Actually the alternative for me is to build a WEB Service in Java that I can call from the tool that I use to create the front end interface and then use Java to send the file to DocuSign. I was trying to see if I can do everything in this tool it's called Logi Studio but I guess not. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[Anchor strings](https://www.docusign.com.au/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm) would be a good option to explore, even moreso if all you need from DocuSign is a Signature (and/or Date Signed) tab.

EDIT: For example, on your document you could whitetext "sig1" where you want the recipient to sign.

```
            "signers": [
          {
            "email": "testsigner@test.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder" : "1",
            "tabs" : {
                "signHereTabs" : [
                    {
                        "tabLabel" : "SignHere",
                        "anchorString" : "sig1"
                    }
                    ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

See the screenshot I've attached. However, I did not white out my anchor. [image]

**One more thing to note. I created the test below from the WebApp. If using the API the bottom left of the tag will apply to the bottom left of the text.**

Comment: Thank you Rickey. The dynamic content that I need to add to the document will be read only. As I mentioned in my post it is essentially like a purchase order. And the dynamic part is not knowing how many details there will be, 1 or more. I suppose the Signature and Date tabs would have to be placed on the bottom of the details. I didn't see the syntax for Anchor Strings in any of the Envelope sample documents and even the search for Anchor came back with 0 results. Do you have a working sample by chance?

Comment: Updated my answer with a brief example. One thing to note is you will want to make your anchors unique as the system will add that tag to EVERY instance of the anchor on a document.

Comment: OK I added a sample picture to the original post of what I need to produce.