# DocuSign - Dynamic Template Stucture

Tags: pdf, docusignapi

I want to know if it is possible generate a dynamic pdf.

Let me tell you more about what we want and if you can help us:

We have an entity called "Application" what we want to do is from the Application data generate a pdf. The problem is that the application does not have the same "structure" always. The application has a list of questions. And the number of question could be or not the same for all the applications.

So If I upload a template with 4 possible questions, but my application have 5 I will not able to map the data correctly.

So basically the structure of the pdf is based on my entity "Application".

I have research about this and found this question:

[Docusign: Creating a Document with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151325/docusign-creating-a-document-with-dynamic-content)

They ask for a Purchase Order that has some detail data that is not allways the same.

So I was wondering if my scenario is the same as the question?

Do you have any kind of solution for this?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use DocuSign server template in this scenario as generated PDF is dynamic in nature, instead when you are generating PDF on your end then think of generating PDF to use either Anchor String or create PDF Field Names as per DS Standards so that DocuSign can automatically place DS Tabs on the PDF.

Anchor String is already explained in the link which you shared in your post. To create PDF Field Names you can refer to [PDF Field Transformation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm#Transfor) and to use that PDF fields for creating an envelope is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189713/docusign-transform-pdf-fields-for-multiple-recipients)

Comment: Amit, Thanks for your answer. I have another question. The composite template can not help me in this case too? Thanks!

Comment: DocuSign does not generate any PDF from your source data, so neither Composite nor any design pattern would be able to solve this issue. You need to generate PDF on your end in a way that DocuSign can understand where to place the DS Tabs. Composite Template is a design strategy to create an envelope based on the PDF provided by you either using DS Server Template or Runtime PDF or both.

Answer (score 0):

I will add to Amit's fine answer some additional comments:

1. As Amit says, your app needs to compose the document. You can compose the document in PDF or in other formats. HTML can be a good alternative to PDF since it is often easier to create. You can include css and graphics inline since external css and image files are not supported.
2. You can add additional document(s) to an envelope if you want. So the base agreement can be one document and the variable data can be another.
3. Your envelope (a set of documents) can include a "signing page" as the last document, this could be a constant document.
4. When you add a document to an envelope, you can apply a template to it. That way the anchor strings in the document will be used for field (tab) placement.
5. After you add a document to an envelope, your app can explicitly add additional tabs (fields) to the document--you don't have to use a template for doing this.
6. Compositing Templates and documents together can be used to create an envelope that includes multiple templates and documents. If you're creating a document dynamically for an envelope, Composite Templates may not be as needed.